# Assign JDBC connection from Java to R

Tags: java, r, rjava, jri

I would like to create JDBC connection in java and pass it to R.
R would use it to write data to database.
Can it be done? Is JRI running inside JVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like this:

```
Java (create JDB connection) -> call R -> load Java via rJava -> call Java
```

it will not work. You have two, different JVMs.

If you want to do something like this:

```
R -> call Java via rJava (create JDB connection) -> call Java yet again
```

it should work as you are inside one JVM.

You can think about introducing some helper class (e.g. Singleton that keeps your connection object). This way, you won't be forced to pass it around.

Comment: I wanted to use first case. So I will then do all queries in my JVM   and pass huge amounts of data via JRI. R would pass huge amounts of data back and I will persist it to DB. Works for rJdbc, should work for me. I hope...

Comment: If you want to use JDB connection, maybe you can simply store data inside DB and read/write it inside R? This way, you won't push data via JRI calls.